# Why does Swift Array contains(_:) method accept nil argument when it must be non-optional?

Tags: ios, swift

I simplified my code as much as I could to make it still be a reproducible example.
When I use `contains` like this in a chain of calls it does compile, work and `contains` accepts `nil` when it shouldn't, I think.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter { _ in
    [1, 2, 3].map { smallNumber in
        "\(smallNumber)"
    }
    .contains(nil)
}
```

But when I assign `map` result to a variable and then call `contains` with `nil` value the code doesn't even compile.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter { _ in
    let mappedNumbers = [1, 2, 3].map { smallNumber in
        "\(smallNumber)"
    }
    return mappedNumbers.contains(nil)
}
```

Xcode is complaining about `'nil' is not compatible with expected argument type 'String'`, that is right.

I expect the same error in the first example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler can automatically wrap a value into an optional, if required by the context. That is what makes simple assignments like

```
let value: Int? = 123
```

possible. In your first example, the return type of the closure is inferred as `String?` from the context, so that the `map` returns `[String?]`, and `.contains(nil)` can be applied to it. I.e. the compiler understands the code as

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter { _ in
    [1, 2, 3].map { smallNumber -> String? in
        "\(smallNumber)"
    }
    .contains(nil)
}
```

In the second example the compiler does not have that context, and `mappedNumbers` has the type `[String]`. You can make it compile by specifying the closure return type `String?` explicitly:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter { _ in
    let mappedNumbers = [1, 2, 3].map { smallNumber -> String? in
        "\(smallNumber)"
    }
    return mappedNumbers.contains(nil)
}
```

Comment: Or `let mappedNumbers: [String?] = [1, 2, 3].map { smallNumber in
        "\(smallNumber)" }` which, IMO is more like what the compiler is doing in the first example.